# Vertical alignment of geom_tile plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have data from three different studies which I'm plotting using `ggplot2`'s `geom_tile`. The columns are `category` - to be plotted on the y-axis, `x` - the x-axis, and `score` - which will be color coding the tiles. The `study` column specifies the study.

Here are the data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(category=strsplit("Peptide,Amino Acid,Nucleotide,Xenobiotics,Carbohydrate,Cofactors and Vitamins,Lipid,Lysophospholipid,Gamma-glutamyl Amino Acid,Leucine  Isoleucine and Valine Metabolism,Fatty Acid  Dicarboxylate,Long Chain Fatty Acid,Sterol,Secondary Bile Acid Metabolism,Polyunsaturated Fatty Acid (n3 and n6),Other Tentative Assignments,Energy,Cofactors And Vitamins,Sulfur Metabolism,Amino Acids,Carnitine And Fatty Acid Metabolsim,Glycerophospholipid Biosynthesis,Stimulating/Exogenous Compounds,Carboxylic Acid,Bile Acids,Gamma-Glutamyls,Arachidonate Metabolism,Gsh Homeostasis,Medium Chain Fatty Acid,Urea cycle; Arginine and Proline Metabolism",split=",")[[1]],
                 x=rep("x",30),score=log10(runif(30,0,1)),study=c(rep("study1",12),rep("study2",10),rep("study3",8)),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'm plotting each study separately using `geom_tile`, but defining the `width` argument in `geom_tile` to be 0.5 for all three plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot1 <- ggplot(data=df %>% dplyr::filter(study == "study1"),aes(x=x,y=category))+geom_tile(aes(fill=score),width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue',mid='white',high='darkred')+
  theme_minimal()+xlab("")+labs(fill="score")+ylab("Pathway")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),plot.title=element_text(size=16,hjust=0,face="bold"),axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),axis.text=element_text(size=16),legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))+ggtitle("A.")

plot2 <- ggplot(data=df %>% dplyr::filter(study == "study2"),aes(x=x,y=category))+geom_tile(aes(fill=score),width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue',mid='white',high='darkred')+
  theme_minimal()+xlab("")+labs(fill="score")+ylab("Pathway")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),plot.title=element_text(size=16,hjust=0,face="bold"),axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),axis.text=element_text(size=16),legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))+ggtitle("B.")

plot3 <- ggplot(data=df %>% dplyr::filter(study == "study3"),aes(x=x,y=category))+geom_tile(aes(fill=score),width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low='darkblue',mid='white',high='darkred')+
  theme_minimal()+xlab("")+labs(fill="score")+ylab("Pathway")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),plot.title=element_text(size=16,hjust=0,face="bold"),axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),axis.text=element_text(size=16),legend.text=element_text(size=16),legend.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))+ggtitle("C.")
```

Then, I'm trying to put them in a single figure using `gridExtra`'s `arrangeGrob` function, where I want them aligned vertically but that doesn't seem to work:

```
library(gridExtra)

combined.plot <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(grobs=list(plot1,plot2,plot3),ncol=1,nrow=3)
```

Because this is what I'm getting:

[image]

So my question is how to create a figure where the three plots come out with exactly the same tile widths and aligned vertically (i.e., the tiles are aligned rather than the long category text).

Comment: I'd suggest using facets for the 3 studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `ggarrange` from package `ggpubr`:

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, nrow = 3, align = "v")
```

[image]

PS:

- Similar result can be achieved with `egg::ggarrange`, however it misaligns y-lab for plot B (no white space added): `egg::ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3)`
- Not to type in all plots you can use argument `plotlist` and function `mget`: `ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = mget(paste0("plot", 1:3)), nrow = 3, align = "v")`